# dropdownlist name has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu, updates

What I want to achieve is when I click on edit, the Blogtype field in the gridview will be changed to dropdownlist. And Since my database have 3 data in the blogtype which is community work, competition and overseas experience. The dropdownlist will be allows me to select either of these three. After choosing either of this one, and I clicked update, it will be updated in the database. How to do it as I have error in the 3rd screenshot.The name of my dropdownlist for blogtype field is ddlBlogType. help

[image]

[image]

But for my current code, after clicking edit, it will come out this error. 'ddlBlogType' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.
Parameter name: value
[image]

**Source Code**

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdBlog" runat="server" style=
"margin-left: 0px" Width="1000px" Height="147px" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                        onrowcancelingedit="grdBlog_RowCancelingEdit" onrowediting="grdBlog_RowEditing" 
                        onrowupdating="grdBlog_RowUpdating" DataKeyNames="BlogID" 
                        onrowdeleting="grdBlog_RowDeleting" AllowPaging="True" 
                        onpageindexchanging="grdBlog_PageIndexChanging" PageSize="5" 
            BackColor="White" BorderColor="White" BorderStyle="Ridge" BorderWidth="2px" 
            CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="1" GridLines="None" >
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="BlogID" HeaderText="BlogID" ReadOnly="true" 
                                SortExpression="BlogID" />
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Width="80px" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="BlogType">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlBlogType" runat="server" Width="80px" Text='<%# Bind("BlogType") %>'></asp:DropDownList>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("BlogType") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDescription" runat="server" Width="80px" Text='<%# Bind("Description") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Description") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="DateEntry" HeaderText="Date Entry" ReadOnly="true" />
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Blog Story">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtBlogStory" runat="server" TextMode="multiline" rows="10" Text='<%# Bind("BlogStory") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("BlogStory") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="modifiedby" HeaderText="Last Modified By" ReadOnly="true" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="modifieddate" HeaderText="Last Modified Date" ReadOnly="true" />
                            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" CausesValidation="false" />
                            <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                                        CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" OnClientClick="javascript : return confirm('Confirm delete this record?');"></asp:LinkButton>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                        <FooterStyle BackColor="#C6C3C6" ForeColor="Black" />
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#4A3C8C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#E7E7FF" />
                        <PagerStyle BackColor="#C6C3C6" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                        <RowStyle BackColor="#DEDFDE" ForeColor="Black" />
                        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#9471DE" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
                        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#594B9C" />
                        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
                        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#33276A" />
                    </asp:GridView>
```

**Code Behind Code**

```
if (Page.IsPostBack == false)
        {
            bindResultGridView();

        }

 private void bindResultGridView()
    {
        String ConStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BlogConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConStr);

        try
        {

            String SQL = null;

            SQL = "SELECT BlogID, Name, Blogtype, Description, convert(varchar,Dateentry, 103) as Dateentry, BlogStory, modifiedby, convert(varchar,modifieddate, 103) as modifieddate FROM [EntryTable] ORDER BY BlogID DESC";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL, con);
            con.Open();

            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(reader);
            grdBlog.DataSource = dt;
            grdBlog.DataBind();


            reader.Close();
        }

        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }

 protected void grdBlog_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        grdBlog.EditIndex = -1;
        bindResultGridView();
    }

    protected void grdBlog_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        grdBlog.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        bindResultGridView();
    }
    protected void grdBlog_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        int selectedRow = e.RowIndex;   //get selected row
        //  get product id from data key
        int blogid = (int)grdBlog.DataKeys[selectedRow].Value;

        //  get current grid view row
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)grdBlog.Rows[selectedRow];
        TextBox name = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtName");
        //  find text box for txtPrice
        DropDownList blogtype = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("ddlBlogType");
        TextBox description = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtDescription");
        TextBox blogstory = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtBlogStory");
        //  Remove $ sign
        string strName = name.Text;
        string strBlogType = blogtype.Text;
        string strDescription = description.Text;
        string strBlogStory = blogstory.Text;
        /*
        DateTime datDate;
        */

        /*
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(strDateEntry, new string[] { "dd/MM/yyyy" },
                               System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                               System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out datDate))
        {
         */
            updateBlogGridviewRecord(blogid, strName, strBlogType, strDescription, strBlogStory);
        /*
        }

        else
        {
            lblError.Visible = true;
            lblError.Text = "Invalid Date";
            lblSuccess.Visible = false;
        }
        */
    }

        private void updateBlogGridviewRecord(int blogid, string strName, string strBlogType, string strDescription, string strBlogStory)
        {
            try
            {
                string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BlogConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
                SqlConnection myConnect = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);

                string strCommandText = "UPDATE EntryTable SET [ModifiedBy]=@Modifier, [ModifiedDate] = GETDATE(), [Name]=@Name, [BlogType]=@BlogType, [Description]=@Description, [BlogStory]=@BlogStory WHERE [BlogID]=@BlogID";
                /*string strCommandText = "UPDATE EntryTable SET [Name]=@Name, [BlogType]=@BlogType, [Description]=@Description, [DateEntry]=@DateEntry, [BlogStory]=@BlogStory WHERE [BlogID]=@BlogID"; */
                /*string strCommandText = "UPDATE EntryTable SET [ModifiedBy] = [Name], [Name]=@Name, [BlogType]=@BlogType, [Description]=@Description, [DateEntry]=@DateEntry, [BlogStory]=@BlogStory WHERE [BlogID]=@BlogID"; */

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strCommandText, myConnect);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BlogID", blogid);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", strName);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BlogType", strBlogType);
                //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateEntry", datDate);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", strDescription);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BlogStory", strBlogStory);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Modifier", Session["Username"]);
                myConnect.Open();

                int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                if (result > 0)
                {
                    lblSuccess.Visible = true;
                    lblSuccess.Text = "Record updated!";
                    lblError.Visible = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    lblSuccess.Visible = true;
                    lblError.Text = "Update fail";
                    lblError.Visible = false;
                }

                myConnect.Close();


                //Cancel Edit Mode
                grdBlog.EditIndex = -1;
                bindResultGridView();
            }

            catch
            {
                lblError.Visible = true;
                lblError.Text = "Invalid Data";
                lblSuccess.Visible = false;
            }
        }
```

Did it using the edited code below

**Source Code**

```
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="BlogType">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlBlogType" runat="server" DataTextField="ddlBlogType" DataValueField="ddlBlogType" SelectedValue='<%# Eval("blogType") %>'>                                                                 
                                    <asp:ListItem Enabled="true" Text="Community Work" Value="Community Work"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="Competition" Value="Competition"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="Overseas Experience" Value="Overseas Experience"></asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("BlogType") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
```

**Code behind Code**

```
 protected void grdBlog_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        int selectedRow = e.RowIndex;   //get selected row
        //  get product id from data key
        int blogid = (int)grdBlog.DataKeys[selectedRow].Value;

        //  get current grid view row
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)grdBlog.Rows[selectedRow];
        TextBox name = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtName");
        //  find text box for txtPrice
        DropDownList blogtype = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("ddlBlogType");
        TextBox description = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtDescription");
        TextBox blogstory = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtBlogStory");
        //  Remove $ sign
        string strName = name.Text;
        string strBlogType = blogtype.SelectedValue;
        string strDescription = description.Text;
        string strBlogStory = blogstory.Text;
    }
```

Comment: Its better to do these nature of requirements with a SqlDataSource with all the necessary update commands provided. It has much better support. Can you provide the stacktrace

Comment: The error message indicates you are trying to bind something to the dropdownlist which does not exist in the list.

Answer (score 0):

I see the issue as the way you populate the DropDownList. The code isn't shown in your post, so assuming you don't have anything to that effect.

So you normally set the desired gridviewrow in edit mode as below:

```
protected void grdBlog_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    grdBlog.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    bindResultGridView();
}
```

Now we need to figure when exactly to bind the dropdownlist. Therefore when the particular datarow (which is in edit mode) is getting databound we have a chance to obtain the reference to the corresponding edit row's dropdownlist. Hence for this you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18656909/145682) post.

In summary you need to handle the DataBound event of the gridview and determine from its rowstate what mode it is in. Sharing the code sample from linked post below:

```
protected void gv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0)
        {
            DropDownList ddList= (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("DStatusEdit");
            //bind dropdownlist
            DataTable dt = con.GetData("select distinct status from directory");
            ddList.DataSource = dt;
            ddList.DataTextField = "YourCOLName";
            ddList.DataValueField = "YourCOLName";
            ddList.DataBind();

            DataRowView dr = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;
            //ddList.SelectedItem.Text = dr["YourCOLName"].ToString();
            ddList.SelectedValue = dr["YourCOLName"].ToString();
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Edited my post above. I did it using that code above. The error means that the dropdownlist in the source code must match the value in the database. I created three <asp:ListItem Text> in the dropdownlist that matches what I have in the database. and I change strBlogType = blogtype.Text; to string strBlogType = blogtype.SelectedValue;.   @deostroll

Comment: That means it's more troublesome for me as I need to always match the code in my dropdownlist to the value in the database. I think it's better to just populate the data from just the database. Will look at your codes. @deostroll

Comment: I suppose you r binding the dropdownlist in markup. Remove the `Text` attribute.